# selectedIndex in comboBox don't return correct integer in some cases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

after a whiling programming in c#, I figure out when we have equal Items in comboBox we can't get correct selectedIndex.
Imagine we have ComboBox with this items:

[image]

And I want to receive 2 when I select third item in ComboBox, but I always receive 0.
And I wantto receive 4 when I select fifth item in ComboBox, but I always receive 3.

I think `SelectedIndex` in `ComboBox` always return the first element of ComboBox.

How can I get selected item index from comboBox with equal Items?

Comment: I don't get the sense of having same text in combobox

Comment: How do you select items? Show some code.

Comment: I suspect you are binding to List<String>.  String is a reference type but it overrides = and it finds the first value match.  Create a simple class that just has a single string property.

Comment: I fully agree with @Blam, it's a matter of the `string` class returning true in the `Equals` method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem at all. Not even when binding the ItemsSource to a List<String> as proposed by Blam and HighCore. My example works fine. Can you elaborate? With a code sample possibly?

Comment: It's not really common to use the `SelectedIndex` in WPF for anything. You should have a `public string SelectedString` somewhere in your ViewModel and bind the `SelectdItem` of the combobox to that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are binding to List String.
String is a reference type but it overrides = and it finds the first value match.
Create a simple class that just has a single string property.

```
public class SimpleString
{
    public string StrValue { get; set; }
    public SimpleString() { }
    public SimpleString(string strValue) { StrValue = StrValue;  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not binding from a list<String>, but I'm using foreach(...) to add all list<string> to comboBox.Items

Comment: Add or bind it is string and it finds the first value match.  Did you try the solution I proposed?

Comment: Dear I used foreach() for adding Item in Items of comboBox from a lis<String>, and I didn't got right SelectedIndex, but now I use another approach that there is no same Item in Items list.

Answer (score 1):

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<String> list = new List<string>();

    public List<String> List { get { return this.list; } set { this.list = value; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list.Add("methode");
        list.Add("methode");
        list.Add("methode");
        list.Add("methode2");
        list.Add("methode2");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Temp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
                  SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

works fine for me. Can you elaborate your question? Mind you I tried all different kind of types and always got a working result so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a checkbox model class which will contain Name and Id properties. 
Then init the comboBox'es property `DisplayMember` and `DataMember` to that properties.
Now assign a `DataSource` property of the comboBox to the list of your custom items.

Since elements of the DataSource now aren't equal (by reference), they won't be considered equal and you'll be able to get the `SelectedValue`. `SelectedIndex` will work probably as well, but that's not the best approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the meaning of having same text with different value anyway use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedIndex`.

If you absolutely need the index you can loop the combobox items...

Comment: I need the Index of that item in ComboBox.

Comment: @Ahadaghapour as i say in the answer just loop throught the dropdown items and compare the value with the selected value